# USB WiFi Access Point Set Nickname

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, hotspot

I have created a WiFi access point and I want to set the nickname field...

I am trying to set it using;

```
iwconfig wlan0 nick AP_NICK
```

However I am getting an unsupported error which. The USB Dongle is an Edimax EW-7711UAn, using the RT2X00USB driver.

My question is, is it the firmware/chipset or something else that is stopping me setting the APs nickname? Is there anyway around this?

If there is nothing I can do, does anyone have a suggestion on USB WiFi chipsets/drivers/dongles with this capability?

Comment: Don't use cheap, consumer-oriented WLAN chips as an AP.

Answer (score 0):

The "NickName" is essid, you can change this using the following command:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid "Here's NickName"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the essid and nickname are different options.

Comment: Hmm, then, what's "nick" option ?

Comment: The nickname is essentially just a bit of extra meta data describing the WiFi access point. The iwconfig man page describes it as a station name as opposed to a network name (essid). It is useful to differentiate between multiple access points on the same network.

Comment: I read man page, and in example it's use "nickname" you already tested with "nickname" ?

`[...]iwconfig eth0 nickname "My Linux Node"`